# invalid syntax and program error

Tags: stata

```
forvalue n=1/18 {
    if f_3_`n'_==1 {
        local i= `0'
        local y=`i'+1 
            gen ownagri_`y' = f123a_`y'_
            replace ownagri_`y' = . if f_2_sel_`n' ==1 
        local i = `i'+1
    }
    else if f_3_`n'_==2 {
        local i= `0'
        local y=`i'+1 
            gen agri_`y' = f126_a1_`n'_
            replace agri_`y' = .if f_2_sel_`n' ==1 
        local i = `i'+1
    }
    else if f_3_`n'_==3 {
        local i= `0'
        local y=`i'+1 
            gen nonagri_`y' = f126_a1_`n'_
            replace nonagri_`y' = . if f_2_sel_`n' ==1 
        local i = `i'+1
    }
    else if f_3_`n'_==4 {
        local i=`0'
        local y=`i'+1 {
            gen nonagriself_`y' = f128_`n'_
            replace nonagriself_`y' = . if f_2_sel_`n' ==1 
        local i = `i'+1
    }
    else if f_3_`n'_==5 {
        local i=`0'
        local y=`i'+1 
            gen military_`y' = . if f_2_sel_`n' ==1  
        local i = `i'+1
    }}
}
```

Stata says my command contains invalid syntax and there is **program error**:  code follows on the same line as close brace.

**EDIT:**

```
forvalue n = 1/18 {
    if f_3_`n'_==1 {
        local y1 = 1 
        gen ownagri_`y1' = f123a_`y1'_ 
        replace ownagri_`y' = . if f_2_sel_`n'_ ==1 
        local y1 = `y1'+1
    }
    else if f_3_`n'_==2 {
        local y2 = 1 
        gen agri_`y2' = f126_a1_`y2'_ 
        replace agri_`y2' = . if f_2_sel_`n'_ ==1 
        local y2 = `y2'+1
    }
    else if f_3_`n'_==3 {
        local y3 = 1
        gen nonagri_`y3' = f126_a1_`y3'_ 
        replace nonagri_`y3' = . if f_2_sel_`n'_ ==1 
        local y3 = `y3'+1
    }
    else if f_3_`n'_==4 {
        local y4 = 1
        gen nonagriself_`y4' = f128_`y4'_ 
        replace nonagriself_`y4' = . if f_2_sel_`n'_ ==1 
        local y4 = `y4'+1
    }
    else if f_3_`n'_==6 {
        local y5 = 1
        gen military_`y5' = f129a_`y5'_
        replace military_`y5' = . if f_2_sel_`n'_ ==1 ,modify
        local y5 = `y5'+1
    }
}
```

I modified the code and the program seems to work, but the results generated seem to be incomplete. The result shows as follow:

```
(20,070 missing values generated)
(2,194 real changes made, 2,194 to missing)
(19,229 missing values generated)
(1,129 real changes made, 1,129 to missing)
```

Why?

Comment: You show two close braces on the next to last line of the code you post. That is one more than should be there. The "code" Stata complains about is the second close brace.

Comment: but if I deleted one STATA will show unexpected end of file, still not working..

Comment: I have corrected the brace.... but there is still invalid syntax..

Comment: See also http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/ Lines like `if f_3_\`n'_==1` are evaluated as `if f_3_\`n'_[1] ==1` which is usually not what is wanted.

Comment: I have read through the article... is there any ways I can solve this problem?

Comment: Latest question seems unanswerable. We can't see the data; we don't know what would be the right answer substantively.

Comment: Question is cycling around "How can I program what I want to do?" Not answerable with a clear statement on data and what you want. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific comments already made:

a. The `}}` on the next to last line should be `}` (William Lisowski)

b. Lines like

```
if f_3_`n'_==1
```

are evaluated as if

```
if f_3_`n'_[1] ==1
```

which is usually not what is wanted. See [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/) for much more. But this is not a syntax error.

New specific comment:

c. The line

```
local y=`i'+1 {
```

has a spurious `{` that should be removed.

General comments:

A. Throwing a large chunk of code at us without context is poor question style. You're new to this, which is fine, but equally there is accessible advice for you to follow e.g. [on good examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

B. There is no context here on what you are trying to do and no data example. The Statalist advice on how to present data examples in [its FAQ](https://www.statalist.org/forums/help#stata) carries over to other sites with easy small modifications (e.g. the advice there on delimiters [CODE] and {/CODE] is irrelevant here).

C. There is repeated code in every branch which can be moved, producing this:

```
local i = `0'
local y = `i'+1 

forvalue n = 1/18 {
    if f_3_`n'_==1 {
        gen ownagri_`y' = f123a_`y'_
        replace ownagri_`y' = . if f_2_sel_`n' ==1 
    }
    else if f_3_`n'_==2 {
        gen agri_`y' = f126_a1_`n'_
        replace agri_`y' = .if f_2_sel_`n' ==1 
    }
    else if f_3_`n'_==3 {
        gen nonagri_`y' = f126_a1_`n'_
        replace nonagri_`y' = . if f_2_sel_`n' ==1 
    }
    else if f_3_`n'_==4 {
        gen nonagriself_`y' = f128_`n'_
        replace nonagriself_`y' = . if f_2_sel_`n' ==1 
    }
    else if f_3_`n'_==5 {
        gen military_`y' = . if f_2_sel_`n' ==1  
    }
}

local i = `i'+1
```

Whether this code is what you want we cannot say, but it looks legal, and it's shorter than your original.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience !!! I'm sorry for my poor quality question... will improve it next time

Comment: First, is it possible to have 'local' within the forvalue command? Becuase y shoule be like y1 y2 y3 y4 y5... for each possible scenario , they are not the same...

Comment: You can loop over 1 to 5 and refer to `y\`local'` inside the loop. 3 out of 4 examples in `help forvalues` are of this form, so it is prominently documented.